# Performing math on a column from two separate queries

Tags: mysql

Relatively new to MySQL, but I've been using it for a few months now and have been asked to do some math based on some numbers.  Figured it's far better to have mysql do that for me since there's a LOT of records.  I'll do my best to explain what I'm after; here's a snippet of results.

```
SELECT attempt_number, date(initiated_at) as day,phone_number, count(*) FROM table WHERE phone_number IN (<a bunch of numbers>) AND initiated_at > '2014-08-01 00:00:00' and initiated_at < date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute) and attempt_number in (1, 2) and attempt_number IS NOT NULL group by phone_number,day, attempt_number;


+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+
| attempt_number | day        | phone_number | count(*) |
+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+
|              1 | 2014-08-04 |   0000000000 |        2 |
|              2 | 2014-08-04 |   0000000000 |        1 |
+----------------+------------+--------------+----------+
```

The above results is an example for a single day and phone number (there are thousands records, in actuality).  It can be assumed that all phone_number records have a attempt_number 1, but not all have a 2.  What I'm ultimately after is, on a per-day basis (as set by "date as day" above), the percentage of calls for a list of phone numbers that has had a second attempt.  For the above results, I need an output like so:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+
| day        | phone_number | percentage |
+------------+--------------+------------+
| 2014-08-04 |   0000000000 |         67 |
+------------+--------------+------------+
```

Does this make sense?  I tried some wizardry with variables, but I got hung up.  Perhaps that's not the best way to go about this. (I do know how to perform math and work with variables.  It's just that these results are formed specifically because of how they're grouped by day).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT date(initiated_at) as day, attempt_number,
       sum(attempt_number = 1) as attempt1,
       sum(attempt_number = 2) as attempt2,
       avg(attempt_number = 1)*100 as percentage
FROM table
WHERE phone_number IN (<a bunch of numbers>) AND
      initiated_at > '2014-08-01 00:00:00' and
      initiated_at < date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute) and
      attempt_number in (1, 2) and
      attempt_number IS NOT NULL
group by date(initiated_at), phone_number;
```

MySQL treats booleans as numbers, so true is "1" and false is "0".  You can then use `sum()` to count the number of times something is true.  The `avg()` returns the proportion of times that something is true.

Comment: +1. This is how I would do it, this is the most straightforward approach. Note that there's a potential for the `SUM()` aggregates to return NULL; we may want to handle those NULL values as zeros, with an appropriate wrapper function, to replace NULL values with zeros. Note that the `attempt_number IS NOT NULL` predicate is redundant with the `attempt_number IN ()` predicate. Any rows that have an `attempt_number` that satisfies the `IN ()` predicate are guaranteed to be `NOT NULL`.

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . They can't return `NULL`.  The `where` clause limits the rows to values where there is at least one row with those values.  The conditions evaluate to `0` or `1`, so there is no possibility of `NULL` values (if `attempt_number` were `NULL` the row would be filtered out).

Comment: *DOH!* Yes. I was wrong about that. You are definitely right. We are already guaranteed that `attempt_number` is NOT NULL (I actually made that point in my comment). The comparison of that to a non-NULL value is guaranteed *not* to return NULL.

Comment: That mostly did the trick!  From the initial SELECT statement, I added phone_number (because it's important to know which one it was) and removed attempt_number (because it all came back as 1 anyway, indicating it wasn't null as mentioned above).  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT day, phone_number, FLOOR(100 * count1/(count1+count2)) AS percentage
FROM (
    SELECT date(initiated_at) AS day, phone_number, 
            IFNULL(SUM(attempt_number = 1), 0) AS count1, 
            IFNULL(SUM(attempt_number = 2), 0) AS count2
    FROM table
    WHERE ...
    GROUP by day, phone_number) AS subquery
```

Comment: This should return the specified result. But I'd opt to avoid the performance overhead of materializing the derived table; it's not necessary, the result can be obtained without an inline view.

Comment: That requires repeating the `IFNULL(SUM(...))` expression, which makes the query very hard to read. If performance is a problem, he can rewrite it that way.

Answer (score 0):

simple trick

```
SELECT DATE(initiated_at) AS day,phone_number, 
COUNT( CASE attempt_number WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) / COUNT( CASE attempt_number WHEN 1 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END ) * 100
FROM TABLE
WHERE phone_number IN ('000')
AND attempt_number IN (1, 2) AND attempt_number IS NOT NULL GROUP BY phone_number,DATE(initiated_at);
```